# EF6 with User defined data types in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 and i created a stored procedure having a parameter of user defined data type. so when i added the stored procedure to the model browser.. EF cannot find the parameters with user defined data types. Is it ok to edit the DbContext or is there a way to fix this?